# Can not cancel Queries

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Ok Not sure what is going on here. I have runaway queries that won't cancel. I have one query to select all rows from a table that only has 250 rows and is 1.5KB in size. It's been running for 30 minutes right now and it should only take a few ms.

I've tried canceling by hitting the abort button on the worksheet, going into history and selecting the query and hitting abort, aborting based on the query ID via SQL, and aborting based on the session ID via SQL.

Ironically whenever I try to abort via SQL it shows that the queries have been terminated and then they still show as running, I wait a few minutes and re run the query and it again shows as terminated but they still are running.

I also tried loggin out and logging back in again and am seeing all kinds of weird errors:

- Internal Error: Unable to retrieve the current roles.
- Error
- Problem with your MFA Enrollment: There was an issue with  your enrollment
  process. Please try again.
- Worksheet Not Loaded

I have no idea what is going on but it seems like everywhere I turn there is an issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging completely out, close the browser, reboot your machine, and start from there.  Here my guess:

- Sometimes the query history (which I assume is where you were seeing things still running), needs a browser refresh, but based on MFA errors, refreshing your browser appears to have you logged out of your SAML/MFA process.
- Once you successfully login, you'll likely see that the query had completed already before you even tried to cancel it.

If that isn't the case, and you are still seeing issues, then we'd probably need more information, or a quick call to Snowflake Support will walk you through things.  My guess is this is all a display issue on your browser/UI, rather than something going wonky with Snowflake.